# Brick Breaker Random Color

Tags: java

The problem I'm having is that when I run the game, instead of staying as one random color, the bricks will keep changing color while I'm in game. How do I fix this so that each brick will stay as one color?

```
public class Game extends JoeApplet implements KeyListener
{
    String status;
    int ballx = 294; // ball spawn x coordinate
    int bally = 640; // ball spawn y coordinate
    int batx = 294; 
    int baty = 654;
    int brickx = 32;
    int bricky = 50;    
    double movex = -16;  // x speed of ball
    double movey = -16;  //y speed of ball
    int count = 0;
    int currentLevel=0;
    int score=0;      //starts score at 0
    int lives=3;      //lives start at 3
    static boolean right = false;
    static boolean left = false;
    boolean ballFallDown = false;
    boolean bricksOver = false;
    Rectangle Ball = new Rectangle(ballx, bally, 12, 12); //creates ball
    Rectangle Bat = new Rectangle(batx, baty, 100, 12);   //creates bat(paddle)
    Rectangle[] Brick = new Rectangle[49];    //creates desired number of bricks
    Random random = new Random();
    static final float MIN_SAT = 0.8f;
    Color color;

    public void paint(Graphics art)
    {
        switch(currentLevel)
        {
        case 0:
            menuScreen(art);
            break;
        case 1:
            game(art);
            break;
        }
    }
    public void menuScreen(Graphics art)
    {
         setSize(700, 700);
         art.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         art.fillRect(0, 0, 698, 698);
         Color ballcolor=new Color(0,0,66);
         art.setColor(ballcolor);
         art.fillOval(Ball.x, Ball.y, Ball.width, Ball.height);
         Color batcolor=new Color(0,0,66);
         art.setColor(batcolor);
         art.fill3DRect(Bat.x, Bat.y, Bat.width, Bat.height, true); 
         art.setColor(Color.green);
         art.drawRect(0, 0, 698, 698);
         art.setColor(Color.yellow);
         Font menu = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
         art.setFont(menu);
         art.drawString("Brick Breaker", 100,400);
         art.drawString("Press P to Play", 100,425);
         art.drawString("Press Q to Quit game", 100,450);
         for (int i = 0; i < Brick.length; i++) 
         {
             if (Brick[i] != null)
             {
                 Color mycolor=new Color(100,0,0);
                 art.setColor(mycolor);
                 art.fill3DRect(Brick[i].x, Brick[i].y, Brick[i].width,
                 Brick[i].height, true);
             }

         }
             art.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
             if (ballFallDown || bricksOver) 
             {
                 Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
                 art.setFont(f);
                 art.drawString(status, 294, 349);
                 ballFallDown = false;
                 bricksOver = false;
             }      
    }
     private  Color color;

    class Brick {
        public  Color getColor() { return color; }
        public  Brick()
        {

            float hue = random.nextFloat();
            float saturation = MIN_SAT + random.nextFloat() * (1f - MIN_SAT);
            float brightness = MIN_SAT + random.nextFloat() * (1f - MIN_SAT);
            Color color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, 
            brightness);

        }
     }
    public void game(Graphics art) 
    {
         setSize(700, 700);
         art.setColor(Color.BLACK);
         art.fillRect(0, 0, 698, 698);
         Color ballcolor=new Color(0,0,225);
         art.setColor(ballcolor);
         art.fillOval(Ball.x, Ball.y, Ball.width, Ball.height);
         Color batcolor=new Color(0,0,139);
         art.setColor(batcolor);
         art.fill3DRect(Bat.x, Bat.y, Bat.width, Bat.height, true); 
         art.setColor(Color.green);
         art.drawRect(0, 0, 698, 698);
         for (int i = 0; i < Brick.length; i++) 
         {
             if (Brick[i] != null)
             {

                 art.setColor(Brick[i].getColor());
                 art.fill3DRect(Brick[i].x, Brick[i].y, Brick[i].width,
                 Brick[i].height, true);
             }

         }

             if (ballFallDown || bricksOver) 
             {
                 Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
                 art.setFont(f);
                 art.drawString(status, 100,425);
                 ballFallDown = false;
                 bricksOver = false;
             }  

             for (int i = 0; i < Brick.length; i++)
             {
                    if (Brick[i] != null) 
                    {
                        if (Brick[i].intersects(Ball)) 
                        {
                            score=score+10;
                            Brick[i] = null;
                            movey = -movey;
                            count++;
                        }   
                    }
             }      


               if (count == Brick.length) 
               {
                   bricksOver = true;
                   movex=0;
                   movey=0;
                   art.setColor(Color.green);
                   status = "YOU BEAT THE LEVEL!!";
                   art.drawString("Press E to Exit", 100,450);
                   art.drawString("Press N for Next Level", 100,475);
                   repaint();
               }

             repaint();
             Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
             art.setFont(f);
             art.setColor(Color.white);
             art.drawString("Score:"+score, 600, 684);
             Ball.x += movex;
             Ball.y += movey;
             if (left == true) 
             {
                 Bat.x -= 18;
                 right = false;
             }
             if (right == true) 
             {
                 Bat.x += 18;
                 left = false;
             }
             if (Bat.x <= 4)
             {
                 Bat.x = 4;
             } 
             else if (Bat.x >= 586)
             {
                 Bat.x = 596;
             }    
             if (Ball.intersects(Bat))
             {
                 movey = -movey-.1;
             }   
             if (Ball.x <= 0 || Ball.x + Ball.height >= 698)
             {
                 movex = -movex;
             }
             if (Ball.y <= 0) 
             {
                 movey = -movey;
             }
             Font f1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
             art.setFont(f1);
             art.setColor(Color.white);
             art.drawString("Lives:"+ lives, 5, 684);
             if (Ball.y >= 698 && (bricksOver==false) && lives>0) 
             {
                   ballFallDown = true;
                   art.setColor(Color.red);
                   status = "";
                   art.drawString("", 100,450);
                   lives=lives-1;
                   ballx = 294; 
                   bally = 640;
                   Ball = new Rectangle(ballx, bally, 12, 12);
                   movex = -16;
                   movey = -16;
                   repaint();  
             } 
             if(lives==0 && Ball.y >= 698)
             {
                 art.setColor(Color.red);
                 art.drawString("You lost!!", 100,425);
                 art.drawString("Press E to Exit", 100,450);
             }
        }   

    public void init() 
    {
        addKeyListener(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < Brick.length; i++)  //creates bricks
        {
            Brick[i] = new Rectangle(brickx, bricky, 40, 20);
            if (i == 12)        //1st row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 32;
                bricky = 84;
            }
            if (i == 23)    //2nd row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 82;
                bricky = 118;
            }
            if (i == 32)    //3rd row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 132;
                bricky = 152;
            }
            if (i == 39)        //4th row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 182;
                bricky = 186;
            }
            if (i == 44)    //5th row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 232;
                bricky = 220;
            }
            if (i == 47)        //6th row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 282;
                bricky = 254;
            }
            if (i == 48)        //7th row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 144;
                bricky = 132;
            }
            brickx += 50;   //spacing between each brick        
        }   
    }

    public void restart()  //if player chooses to exit(E) game will reset back to level one
    {

         ballx = 294; 
         bally = 640;
         batx = 294;
         baty = 654;
         brickx = 32;
         bricky = 50;   
         Ball = new Rectangle(ballx, bally, 12, 12);
         Bat = new Rectangle(batx, baty, 100, 12);
         movex = -16;
         movey = -16;
         ballFallDown = false;
         bricksOver = false;
         count = 0;
        status = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < Brick.length; i++)  //recreates bricks
        {
            Brick[i] = new Rectangle(brickx, bricky, 40, 20);
            if (i == 12)        
            {
                brickx = 32;
                bricky = 84;
            }
            if (i == 23)    
            {
                brickx = 82;
                bricky = 118;
            }
            if (i == 32)    
            {
                brickx = 132;
                bricky = 152;
            }
            if (i == 39)        
            {
                brickx = 182;
                bricky = 186;
            }
            if (i == 44)    
            {
                brickx = 232;
                bricky = 220;
            }
            if (i == 47)        
            {
                brickx = 282;
                bricky = 254;
            }
            if (i == 48)        
            {
                brickx = 144;
                bricky = 132;
            }
            brickx += 50;           
        }   
          repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)  //allows each key to do desired action
    {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) 
        {
            left = true;     
        }

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) 
        {
            right = true;
        }
        if (keyCode == e.VK_P && currentLevel == 0)
        {
            currentLevel = 1;
        }       
        else if (keyCode == e.VK_E && currentLevel == 1)
        {
            currentLevel = 0;
            score=0;
            lives=3;
            restart();
        }   
        else if(keyCode == e.VK_Q)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) 
        {
            left = false;
        }

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            right = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        Game prog = new Game();
        prog.init();        
    }
}
```

Code where I try to give each brick a random color:

```
if (Brick[i] != null)
             {
                 float hue = random.nextFloat();
                 float saturation = MIN_SAT + random.nextFloat() * (1f - 
MIN_SAT);
                 float brightness = MIN_SAT + random.nextFloat() * (1f - 
MIN_SAT);
                 Color color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, 
brightness);
                 art.setColor(color);
                 art.fill3DRect(Brick[i].x, Brick[i].y, Brick[i].width,
                 Brick[i].height, true);
             }

         }
```

Comment: Your question is unclear bro.Plz explain

Answer (score 1):

You generate a random color for each `Brick` inside the `game`-method, which is called from within `paintComponent`. This means: **each time** the screen is repainted, all Bricks get a new `Color`. Instead of going this way, simply apply a random color to each `Brick`, when it's generated and leave it that way. This requires introducing a `Color` as variable in the `Brick`-class. Simplest solution would be to generate the color directly in the constructor:

```
private Color color;

public Brick(){
    ...

    float hue = random.nextFloat();
    float saturation = MIN_SAT + random.nextFloat() * (1f - MIN_SAT);
    float brightness = MIN_SAT + random.nextFloat() * (1f - MIN_SAT);
    color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, 

    ...
}
```

As use the color stored in `Brick` in the `game`-method to render each `Brick`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Brick.length; i++) 
     {
         if (Brick[i] != null)
         {
             art.setColor(Brick[i].getColor());
             art.fill3DRect(Brick[i].x, Brick[i].y, Brick[i].width, Brick[i].height, true);
         }

     }
```

And some general advice:
Please refactor your code and implement the advice we gave you about your code on the last question you asked. Going further down the path you're currently on, you'll wind up with code that is simply unreadable and can't be debugged. I know we shouldn't introduce any anecdotes here, but when I started coding, I wrote Snake in pretty much the same spaghetti-code style you're using now. In the end I had one small mistake I wanted to fix, so I changed one line of code. Result: the entire code broke, and I wasn't able to fix anything from that point, simply because the code was unusable. Moral of the story: in spaghettic-code fixing one bug introduces 100 new bugs. Write proper code, and live happily.

Here's the fixed code:

```
public class Game extends JoeApplet implements KeyListener
{
    String status;
    int ballx = 294; // ball spawn x coordinate
    int bally = 640; // ball spawn y coordinate
    int batx = 294;
    int baty = 654;
    int brickx = 32;
    int bricky = 50;
    double movex = -16;  // x speed of ball
    double movey = -16;  //y speed of ball
    int count = 0;
    int currentLevel=0;
    int score=0;      //starts score at 0
    int lives=3;      //lives start at 3
    static boolean right = false;
    static boolean left = false;
    boolean ballFallDown = false;
    boolean bricksOver = false;
    Rectangle Ball = new Rectangle(ballx, bally, 12, 12); //creates ball
    Rectangle Bat = new Rectangle(batx, baty, 100, 12);   //creates bat(paddle)
    Brick[] Brick = new Brick[49];    //creates desired number of bricks
    Random random = new Random();
    static final float MIN_SAT = 0.8f;

    public void paint(Graphics art)
    {
        switch(currentLevel)
        {
            case 0:
                menuScreen(art);
                break;
            case 1:
                game(art);
                break;
        }
    }
    public void menuScreen(Graphics art)
    {
        setSize(700, 700);
        art.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        art.fillRect(0, 0, 698, 698);
        Color ballcolor=new Color(0,0,66);
        art.setColor(ballcolor);
        art.fillOval(Ball.x, Ball.y, Ball.width, Ball.height);
        Color batcolor=new Color(0,0,66);
        art.setColor(batcolor);
        art.fill3DRect(Bat.x, Bat.y, Bat.width, Bat.height, true);
        art.setColor(Color.green);
        art.drawRect(0, 0, 698, 698);
        art.setColor(Color.yellow);
        Font menu = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
        art.setFont(menu);
        art.drawString("Brick Breaker", 100,400);
        art.drawString("Press P to Play", 100,425);
        art.drawString("Press Q to Quit game", 100,450);
        for (int i = 0; i < Brick.length; i++)
        {
            if (Brick[i] != null)
            {
                art.setColor(Brick[i].getColor());
                art.fill3DRect(Brick[i].x, Brick[i].y, Brick[i].width,
                        Brick[i].height, true);
            }

        }
        art.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        if (ballFallDown || bricksOver)
        {
            Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
            art.setFont(f);
            art.drawString(status, 294, 349);
            ballFallDown = false;
            bricksOver = false;
        }
    }
    private  Color color;

    class Brick
        extends Rectangle
    {
        private Color color;

        public  Color getColor() { return color; }
        public  Brick(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            super(x, y, width, height);

            float hue = random.nextFloat();
            float saturation = MIN_SAT + random.nextFloat() * (1f - MIN_SAT);
            float brightness = MIN_SAT + random.nextFloat() * (1f - MIN_SAT);
            color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation,
                    brightness);
        }
    }
    public void game(Graphics art)
    {
        setSize(700, 700);
        art.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        art.fillRect(0, 0, 698, 698);
        Color ballcolor=new Color(0,0,225);
        art.setColor(ballcolor);
        art.fillOval(Ball.x, Ball.y, Ball.width, Ball.height);
        Color batcolor=new Color(0,0,139);
        art.setColor(batcolor);
        art.fill3DRect(Bat.x, Bat.y, Bat.width, Bat.height, true);
        art.setColor(Color.green);
        art.drawRect(0, 0, 698, 698);
        for (int i = 0; i < Brick.length; i++)
        {
            if (Brick[i] != null)
            {

                art.setColor(Brick[i].getColor());
                art.fill3DRect(Brick[i].x, Brick[i].y, Brick[i].width,
                        Brick[i].height, true);
            }

        }

        if (ballFallDown || bricksOver)
        {
            Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
            art.setFont(f);
            art.drawString(status, 100,425);
            ballFallDown = false;
            bricksOver = false;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < Brick.length; i++)
        {
            if (Brick[i] != null)
            {
                if (Brick[i].intersects(Ball))
                {
                    score=score+10;
                    Brick[i] = null;
                    movey = -movey;
                    count++;
                }
            }
        }


        if (count == Brick.length)
        {
            bricksOver = true;
            movex=0;
            movey=0;
            art.setColor(Color.green);
            status = "YOU BEAT THE LEVEL!!";
            art.drawString("Press E to Exit", 100,450);
            art.drawString("Press N for Next Level", 100,475);
            repaint();
        }

        repaint();
        Font f = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
        art.setFont(f);
        art.setColor(Color.white);
        art.drawString("Score:"+score, 600, 684);
        Ball.x += movex;
        Ball.y += movey;
        if (left == true)
        {
            Bat.x -= 18;
            right = false;
        }
        if (right == true)
        {
            Bat.x += 18;
            left = false;
        }
        if (Bat.x <= 4)
        {
            Bat.x = 4;
        }
        else if (Bat.x >= 586)
        {
            Bat.x = 596;
        }
        if (Ball.intersects(Bat))
        {
            movey = -movey-.1;
        }
        if (Ball.x <= 0 || Ball.x + Ball.height >= 698)
        {
            movex = -movex;
        }
        if (Ball.y <= 0)
        {
            movey = -movey;
        }
        Font f1 = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20);
        art.setFont(f1);
        art.setColor(Color.white);
        art.drawString("Lives:"+ lives, 5, 684);
        if (Ball.y >= 698 && (bricksOver==false) && lives>0)
        {
            ballFallDown = true;
            art.setColor(Color.red);
            status = "";
            art.drawString("", 100,450);
            lives=lives-1;
            ballx = 294;
            bally = 640;
            Ball = new Rectangle(ballx, bally, 12, 12);
            movex = -16;
            movey = -16;
            repaint();
        }
        if(lives==0 && Ball.y >= 698)
        {
            art.setColor(Color.red);
            art.drawString("You lost!!", 100,425);
            art.drawString("Press E to Exit", 100,450);
        }
    }

    public void init()
    {
        addKeyListener(this);
        for (int i = 0; i < Brick.length; i++)  //creates bricks
        {
            Brick[i] = new Brick(brickx, bricky, 40, 20);
            if (i == 12)        //1st row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 32;
                bricky = 84;
            }
            if (i == 23)    //2nd row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 82;
                bricky = 118;
            }
            if (i == 32)    //3rd row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 132;
                bricky = 152;
            }
            if (i == 39)        //4th row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 182;
                bricky = 186;
            }
            if (i == 44)    //5th row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 232;
                bricky = 220;
            }
            if (i == 47)        //6th row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 282;
                bricky = 254;
            }
            if (i == 48)        //7th row of bricks
            {
                brickx = 144;
                bricky = 132;
            }
            brickx += 50;   //spacing between each brick        
        }
    }

    public void restart()  //if player chooses to exit(E) game will reset back to level one
    {

        ballx = 294;
        bally = 640;
        batx = 294;
        baty = 654;
        brickx = 32;
        bricky = 50;
        Ball = new Rectangle(ballx, bally, 12, 12);
        Bat = new Rectangle(batx, baty, 100, 12);
        movex = -16;
        movey = -16;
        ballFallDown = false;
        bricksOver = false;
        count = 0;
        status = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < Brick.length; i++)  //recreates bricks
        {
            Brick[i] = new Brick(brickx, bricky, 40, 20);
            if (i == 12)
            {
                brickx = 32;
                bricky = 84;
            }
            if (i == 23)
            {
                brickx = 82;
                bricky = 118;
            }
            if (i == 32)
            {
                brickx = 132;
                bricky = 152;
            }
            if (i == 39)
            {
                brickx = 182;
                bricky = 186;
            }
            if (i == 44)
            {
                brickx = 232;
                bricky = 220;
            }
            if (i == 47)
            {
                brickx = 282;
                bricky = 254;
            }
            if (i == 48)
            {
                brickx = 144;
                bricky = 132;
            }
            brickx += 50;
        }
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)  //allows each key to do desired action
    {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            left = true;
        }

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            right = true;
        }
        if (keyCode == e.VK_P && currentLevel == 0)
        {
            currentLevel = 1;
        }
        else if (keyCode == e.VK_E && currentLevel == 1)
        {
            currentLevel = 0;
            score=0;
            lives=3;
            restart();
        }
        else if(keyCode == e.VK_Q)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
        {
            left = false;
        }

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
        {
            right = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Game prog = new Game();
        prog.init();
    }
}
```

Pretty hard to fix stuff already.

Comment: Alright, after I get the colored bricks done, I am going to be working on fixing up my code and getting everything to be organized and properly placed. One problem I'm having is that the getColor part of my code is underlined red. How do I fix this?

Comment: @noobcoder create a getter for `color` that is called `getColor()`. I guess it doesn't yet exist in your code. Just create a method like this: `public Color getColor() { return color; }` in `Brick`.

Comment: It is still underlined red. So is the public Color getColor()..etc.

Comment: @noobcoder did you actually place the `getColor()` method inside your definition of `Brick`?

Comment: public void  Brick()
   {
     public  Color getColor() { return color; }
    
       float hue = random.nextFloat();
       float saturation = MIN_SAT + random.nextFloat() * (1f - MIN_SAT);
       float brightness = MIN_SAT + random.nextFloat() * (1f - MIN_SAT);
       Color color = Color.getHSBColor(hue, saturation, 
       brightness);
       
   }

Comment: @noobcoder that'd do for an edit in the actual question... . Anyways: this is not a valid definition of a constructor. And methods don't belong into the constructor. Honestly: you're trying to code way beyond your capabilities with java. Start by learning the java-syntax and the basics of OOP. I can help you solve this, but it won't help you any further than fixing this exact part of the problem. You're simply lacking the required comprehension of how java works. My recommendation: do a tutorial on java and afterwards start over with your project.

Comment: oh ok ;/. But before I stop I want this problem to be fixed. Where am I supposed to place the public Color getColor() { return color; }.

Comment: @noobcoder inside the definition of the class. On the same level, as the definition of the class-variables, like `public int x`, inside the defintion of `Brick`. And the constructor doesn't start with `public void Brick(){...`, but `public Brick(){ ...`. I hope you don't give up on your ambitions :). Coding can be fun, once you've mastered the basics and I don't think you're that far from that point. You've just missed some concepts of OOP and the java-syntax, I guess.

Comment: Oh, I see. But how come when I do public Brick{...Brick is underlined red?

Comment: @noobcoder `public Brick{...` isn't valid either. A constructor always has the format `[accessmodifier] <classname> ( [parameters] ) { ... }`. So in your example: access modifier is `public`, classname is `Brick` and there are no parameters, so `public Brick() { ... }`.

Comment: Oh I see, so what would I enter for the parameters? Is there a way to dm?

Comment: @noobcoder in it's current state your code doesn't need any parameters, so you can just leave the round brackets empty. If you want, you can add the position of the `Brick` as parameter, though that'd require changing quite a bit of the rest of your code. I'd recommend ommiting the parameters, starting with a tutorial and afterwards working through your code.

Comment: public Brick()? I did this and Brick() is underlined red.

Comment: @noobcoder first of all: seriously, please don't try to code any further from your current point. It won't get you anywhere. Did you place the constructor on the top-level of the class-definition of `Brick`? And in general: the errorcodes should tell you what's wrong - at least most of the time.

Comment: alright ;-;. Do you think you can edit my code for me then? So I can at least have some colorful bricks. I am going to look back at tutorials.

Comment: @noobcoder I don't exactly like the idea of doing that, but OK. I'll do that tomorrow - it's pretty late here. In the meantime, pls update the code in your question and add your `Brick`-class, so I can start with the full code base. Putting it online in a CSV-repo or a whatever file-cloud is fine as well, as long as I know where I can find it.

Comment: will do! thank you so much. I will edit the code here in a bit.

Comment: @noobcoder updated with a running Applet, as promised

Comment: Thank you. In the future how would I know when to create a new class? Instead of making one "god class"?

Comment: @noobcoder you start to develop a sense for this kind of stuff with the time. But a good point to start would be to think about what data belongs together. E.g. the position and color a brick belong together, so bundle them into a class. In the next step you would then add methods for handling the data/modifying the Object in some way. E.g. a method to check, whether the ball touches a specific brick. A class should represent a single entity, such as a UI or an element of the UI. If you can think of a class as representing multiple entities, split it up into these entities as single classes.